# "That was me" vs. "That was I"

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-case, copular-verbs, be, predicative-complements

When telling a story about myself from the past, I have found myself in an internal debate over whether the correct way to segue into the present is:

> That was me twelve years ago.

Or:

> That was I twelve years ago.

My instincts tell me the first is correct (object pronoun after a verb and it sounds better to my ears). But, I'm not sure if pronouns after linking verbs should be object pronouns. Which is correct?

Comment: PhpYourCoder, I think that if we are talking about twelve years ago than both are correct, but for an older age I prefer the former.

Comment: Trust your instincts. :) -- Can you imagine anyone saying stuff like: *"That could have been I twelve years ago"*, *"That would have been I if I had gotten married at eighteen"*.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/17745 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2133  http://english.stackexchange.com/a/4655 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/9405 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/62652 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/88319 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/121201 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/125694 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/110601

Comment: This may go the way of the WHO/WHOM distinction...and I think the rule that "if it don't sound right,it ain't right" should apply.                 Imagine knocking on a door and responding to "Who is it?" with "I".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Professor Geoffrey Pullum has this to say:](http://news.ucsc.edu/2002/04/107.html)

> Myth: Expressions like "It was me" and "She was taller than him" are
>   incorrect; the correct forms are "It was I" and "She was taller than
>   he."
>
> Pullum responds: The forms with nominative pronouns sound ridiculously
>   stuffy today. In present-day English, the copular verb takes
>   accusative pronoun complements and so does "than." My advice would be
>   this: If someone knocks at your door, and you say "Who's there?" and
>   what you hear in response is "It is I," don't let them in. It's no one
>   you want to know.
>
> "People have been living in fear of grammar rules that don't exist,"
>   said Pullum, who wrote The Cambridge Grammar with Rodney Huddleston of
>   the University of Queensland, Australia. "We're going into the 21st
>   century carrying grammar books from the 20th century that haven't
>   shaken off grammar myths from the 19th century," said Pullum.

Comment: +1, to counter the silly -1 someone else did. It's good to see someone willing to continually write posts to counteract the silly pedant "rules" that are blindly accepted by students.

Comment: @F.E. Indeed. Here for your delectation, degustation, and deliberation is — perhaps — [an even better rebuttal against all the prissy peevers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7E-aoXLZGY) than Pullum’s. It’s at least more entertaining.

Comment: *"if what you hear in response is "It is I," don't let them in."*  made me chuckle.

Comment: @Omega: Yes, Geoffrey Pullum is an articulate, humorous and sensible (and thus very quotable) linguist. Even if he has been seen associating with 'intransitive prepositions'.

Comment: +1 for citing a reputable source. I appreciate the insight!

Comment: Don't forget that CGEL is a 'grammar book[] from the 20th century'.

Answer (score 6):

My inclination is to say they're *both* correct since in either case your intended meaning is unambiguous.  My ultra-descriptivist streak aside, however, I would think that the second is prescriptively more "correct," since you're using your first person pronoun as a predicate nominative.

Comment: Predicate nominatives existed in Latin, where there was an actual nominative case to mark predicate nouns. But there is no noun case in English; thus predicate nouns have no case. (_I_ is of course not a noun.)

Comment: @Susan: there is no noun case in English (regular nouns have a single case often called "common"), but there is limited case for pronouns: subject, object, possessive. Not even all pronouns show a distinction between subject and object. The non-personal pronouns show no case, and among the personal pronouns "it" and "you" show no subject-object distinction. So that leaves only a handful of pronouns with any subject-object distinction, and in all situations, it's entirely redundant, which explains why people started confusing the forms. Case is dead in English.

Comment: Is it dead, or are the case markers just zero?

Comment: +1 good point and also correct..I appreciate your response!

Comment: @SteelyDan It's dead.  It's kicked the bucket, it's shuffled off its mortal coil, run down the curtain and joined the bleedin' choir invisible.